# bind9 - timed out resolving

Tags: linux, bind9

I have a bind9 server spun up on one of my old test test boxes, and it's close. Everything appears to be working, however I'm getting 'time out resolving' errors spamming my sys.log from what appears to be 3 specific DNS servers...

```
68.237.161.12
68.237.161.14
156.154.71.1
```

bind9 info

```
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: starting BIND 9.14.4 (Stable Release) <id:ab4c496>
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: running on Linux x86_64 4.9.9 #1 SMP Sat Sep 23 11:18:52 EDT 2017
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-threads' '--with-libtool' '--disable-static' '--without-python'
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: running as: named -4 -u named -t /srv/named -c /etc/named.conf
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: compiled by GCC 6.3.0
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: compiled with zlib version: 1.2.11
Jul 25 07:18:59 toe-lfs named[23935]: linked to zlib version: 1.2.11
```

here's a sampling of my sys.log

```
Jul 25 06:24:56 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'ns2prod.18.azuredns-prd.info/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:24:57 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'static.xx.fbcdn.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:24:58 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'azuredns-prd.info/DS/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:24:59 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'azuredns-prd.info/DS/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:26:56 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'settingsfd-geo.trafficmanager.net/A/IN': 156.154.71.1#53
Jul 25 06:26:57 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'settingsfd-geo.trafficmanager.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:26:59 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'settingsfd-geo.trafficmanager.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:27:00 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'beacons.gcp.gvt2.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:27:01 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'beacons.gcp.gvt2.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:26 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'us-ne-courier-4.push-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:27 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gsp-ssl-geomap.ls-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:28 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'us-ne-courier-4.push-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:28 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gsp-ssl-geomap.ls-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:29 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gsp-ssl-gspxramp.ls-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:29 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'e4478.a.akamaiedge.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:29 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'help.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'cds.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'stocks-edge.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'apple-finance.query.yahoo.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'stocks-sparkline.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:30 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gateway-carry.icloud.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.12#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gsp-ssl-gspxramp.ls-apple.com.akadns.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'e4478.a.akamaiedge.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'help.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'cds.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'stocks-edge.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'apple-finance.query.yahoo.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'stocks-sparkline.apple.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'gateway-carry.icloud.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
Jul 25 06:58:31 toe-lfs named[16927]: timed out resolving 'clientservices.googleapis.com/A/IN': 68.237.161.14#53
```

I can include the conf files if they'd be helpful. I would just need to triple check and sanitize them. Any thoughts?

edit: included named.conf

```
acl corpnets {
   localhost;
   172.30.24.0/22;
};

key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-sha256;
    secret "*****some secret key******";
 };

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
        allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
 };

options {
    directory "/etc/namedb";
    pid-file "/var/run/named.pid";
    statistics-file "/var/run/named.stats";

    ## listen-on { 172.30.24.1; };

    managed-keys-directory "/etc";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { corpnets; };
    allow-query { corpnets; };

    allow-transfer { none; };

    forwarders {
                156.154.71.1;
                68.237.161.12;
                68.237.161.14;
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};

zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "root.hints";
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "pz/127.0.0";
};

## zone "30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" {  
##     type master;  
##     file "/etc/namedb/db.30.172";  
## };

zone "24.30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA" {  
type master;  
file "/etc/namedb/db.24.30.172";  
};

// Bind 9 now logs by default through syslog (except debug).
// These are the default logging rules.

logging {
    category default { default_syslog; default_debug; };
    category unmatched { null; };

  channel default_syslog {
      syslog daemon;                      // send to syslog's daemon
                                          // facility
      severity info;                      // only send priority info
                                          // and higher
  };

  channel default_debug {
      file "named.run";                   // write to named.run in
                                          // the working directory
                                          // Note: stderr is used instead
                                          // of "named.run"
                                          // if the server is started
                                          // with the '-f' option.
      severity dynamic;                   // log at the server's
                                          // current debug level
  };

  channel default_stderr {
      stderr;                             // writes to stderr
      severity info;                      // only send priority info
                                          // and higher
  };

  channel null {
      null;                               // toss anything sent to
                                          // this channel
  };
};
```

Comment: What's the role of that BIND9 server? Is it a) acting as an authoritative DNS server for some domain, b) allowing recursive queries and so acting as a resolver DNS server for some clients, or c) both? In general DNS servers in role a) will need to be public, but b) won't have to be, so the current recommendation for enterprises is to separate those roles to different servers. And if c), you should make sure that the `allow-recursion` and `allow-query-cache` options have a restriction list that limits access to legitimate clients only, not allowing the whole world.

Comment: b... completely b.  Caching, and internal name resolution with the end goal being able to limit access to certain domains. This is currently being handled in part by iptables, but I digress... the bind9 config currently set to listen for requests on eno2, which is "my side" of the firewall.

Comment: "_This is currently being handled in part by iptables_" - check out "views". A very powerful way of having bind deliver different information to different IP address ranges.

Comment: "Limiting access vía DNS not resolving" just doesn't work, period. Anybody can filch the address and connect skipping DNS. Yes, non-computer-savy people *will* get the requisite incantations somehow.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion as to what might be causing the timeout messages described? I have a similar problem and would like to understand what might be causing such messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this and fixed it by removing the faulty forwarders.  At the end of each timeout error is an IP from a forwarder from your config, but the errors never complain about google's ns (8.8.8.8).  If you delete the first three forwarders, the errors should go away.